Writing nuclear reactions without the mhchem package
I would like to write nuclear reactions but not with the mhchem package because I have incompatibilities with other chemistry packages.
How can I proceed for example to obtain this type:

Thanks

What other chemistry packages?

I use chemmacro too.

Here's a way to do it, peeked at and adapted from the nuc package.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\nuc}[3]{\ensuremath{{}^{#2}_{#3} \textrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}
 
$ \nuc{X}{A}{Z} \rightarrow  \nuc{Y}{A-a}{Z-z} + \nuc{p}{a}{z} $
 
\end{document}



You can define the \nuc macro using TeX primitives:
\def\nuc#1#2#3{\vcenter{\baselineskip=1.7ex\halign{\hfil##\cr$\nucstyle{#2}$\cr$\nucstyle{#3}$\cr}}{\rm#1}}
\def\nucstyle{\scriptstyle\rm}

Test:
$$
   \nuc{X}{A}{Z} \rightarrow  \nuc{Y}{A-a}{Z-z} + \nuc{p}{a}{z}
$$


If you use the thing inside \ch from chemmacros, you need some more work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Isotope}{mmm}
 {
  \nicolas_isotope:nn { #1 } { #2 } \ensuremath{ \mathrm{#3} }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sup_tl
\tl_new:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sub_tl
\box_new:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sup_box
\box_new:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sub_box
\dim_new:N \l__nicolas_isotope_wd_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nicolas_isotope:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  % override the substitutions made by chemformula
  \cs_set:Nn \chemformula_single_bond: { - }
  \cs_set:Nn \chemformula_triple_bond: { + }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__nicolas_isotope_sup_box { $\scriptstyle\mathrm{#1}$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__nicolas_isotope_sub_box { $\scriptstyle\mathrm{#2}$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__nicolas_isotope_wd_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn
     { \box_wd:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sup_box }
     { \box_wd:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sub_box }
   }
  \ensuremath
   {
    \sp{\makebox[\l__nicolas_isotope_wd_dim][r]{\box_use:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sup_box}}
    \sb{\makebox[\l__nicolas_isotope_wd_dim][r]{\box_use:N \l__nicolas_isotope_sub_box}}
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
\ch{\Isotope{A}{Z}{X} -> \Isotope{A-a}{Z-z}{X} + \Isotope{a}{z}{p}}
\]
\[
\Isotope{A-a}{Z-z}X
\]

\end{document}



Here's an approach using Tikz, if you like. It's a bit more tedious, but gives you access to all those neat options. Here, for example, I put the nuclear objects as text colored in teal (fixed, no passed parameter).
Lengths are set "by eye", can certainly be calculated, and may or may not have problems in other text settings.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pre/.style={font=\tiny}}
 
\newcommand\nuct[3]{%
  \tikz[baseline=-2.8pt,teal]{%                                 baseline adjustment; remove teal
    \node[inner sep=-0.5mm]             (N) at (0,0)    {#1};%  the nuclear object
    \node[pre,yshift= 3pt,anchor=east]      at (N.west) {#2};%  left, up
    \node[pre,yshift=-3pt,anchor=east]      at (N.west) {#3};%  left, down
    \node[inner sep=1pt,anchor=west]        at (N.east) {};%    spacer to right
}}

\begin{document}
 
Hello world: $\nuct{X}{A}{Z} \rightarrow \nuct{Y}{A-a}{Z-z} + \nuct{p}{a}{z}$, here is some text.
 
\end{document}



Using isotope package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{isotope}

\begin{document}
$\isotope[\mathrm A][\mathrm Z]{\mathrm X}\to \isotope[\mathrm{A-a}][\mathrm{Z-z}]{\mathrm Y}+\isotope[a][z]{\mathrm p}$
\end{document}


or tensor package:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$\tensor*[^{\mathrm A}_{\mathrm Z}]{\mathrm{X}}{}\to \tensor*[^{\mathrm{A-a}}_{\mathrm{Z-z}}]{\mathrm Y}{}+\tensor*[^{a}_{z}]{\mathrm p}{}$
\end{document}



I use the chemmacros package which already contains an \isotope command so I cannot use this package which uses the same command.

You can use tensor package.
